# JQuery mCustomScrollbar dynamic height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form with a dropdown list. This list is dynamically generated and I am using mCustomScrollbar to display the elements in dropdown list.

mCustomScrollbar needs height to be fixed in px.

```
<ul class=" customScroll" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" >

                                <li  >1</li>
                                <li >1</li>
                            </ul>
```

script:
I have tried various parameters in the initialization script
i.e:
autoExpandScrollbar

```
 $(".customScroll").mCustomScrollbar();
```

These parameters work fine if there are many li elements but in case of 2-3 `li` elements there is a blank space in the drop down list as the `ul` height exceeds the elements present.

Any idea as to dynamically change the height of the element.

Thanks,

Comment: Sum the height of all children() elements and set it to the parent ul tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem in this way.

First I added 2 classes.

```
.customScroll-auto{ height:auto ; overflow:hidden;}
.customScroll-fixed{ height:150px; overflow:hidden;}
```

Then in my jquery file I checked if the

```
if(array_length > myLimit)
     add class customScroll-fixed to the ul element
else
     add class customScroll-auto to the ul element
```

I don't know if this is the right approach.But it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the height of `customScroll` using:

```
$(function() {
   function getChildrenHeight(element) {
      var height = 0;
      element.children().each(function() {height+= $(this).height();});
      return height;
  }

   $(".customScroll").height(getChildrenHeight($(".customScroll")));
});
```

You can use the function `getChildrenheight()` function with any element to get the height of the element based on its summation of all children height.

Comment: Thanks @mohamedrias for your reply. I guess this approach would work but i followed a different approach.